# Teclado do dispositivo fica sobre o Input

Tags: c#, html, xamarin, input, xamarin.android

Eu tenho uma aplicação em Xamarin usando HybriWebView (telas em HTML). Dentro dela eu tenho um input de texto no final da tela e quando eu clico no input o teclado do celular fica sobre o meu input, logo, não consigo ver o que estou digitando. Achei como soluções na internet adicionar Height a tela quando o input for clicado, mas acredito que tenha uma maneira mais correta de se fazer isso.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Adicionar height na tela é a solução mais correta

Answer (score 1):

A solução mais correta não é adicionar height conforme foi mencionado acima.

Na Activity.cs desejada adicione o seguinte atributo:

`WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan`

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resposta foi tirada do StackOverflow.com: [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)

Comment: Funcionaria se as minhas telas fossem em C#, mas elas são em HTML, portanto esse comando não funciona. :/

Comment: Achei algo sobre isso aqui: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63463/listen-to-virtual-keyboard-keypress-inside-webview. Porém é muito mais complicado do que apenas usar a 'height'. Acho que deveria seguir usando a "gambiarra" mesmo.

Comment: não funcionou aqui também.